# merge unfinished feature into unfinished feature

Tags: git, git-merge, branching-and-merging, git-flow

My project is using [git flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow). My current feature (A) is up for review and will then go into test, which may actually take a few days.
I also have to start the next feature (B) which heavily depends on the first feature (A).

Can I somehow just use git merge to get the branch holding feature (A) into my branch (B) without messing up the flow of git flow?

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take all the content from A and merge into B. It shouldn't affect the branch A and also your B will be duly updated with all dependencies from A

```
git checkout B
git pull origin A
git push origin B
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold feature (A) just with merging feature (A) into (B)

```
git checkout B
git merge A
```

When feature (A) has merged into `develop` branch, try

```
git checkout B
git merge develop
git push origin B
```

Then you can see a Pull Request which only includes diff between B and develop. (Supposing you use GitHub)